# In ruby on rails how to query an associated collection has any record owned by a certain user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Answer.joins(:reviews)
      .where.not(:reviews => {:user_id => 1})
```

For example, above, I want to find all Answer records which do not have a review by user 1.  The query I pasted does not seem to work.

Comment: what is wrong with the query?

Comment: Doesn't work.  Returns 0 results.

Comment: I rephrase, do you want to find all Answer records which do not have even a single review for the User with the specific id ?

Comment: Right,  I want all answer records which the user didn't contribute a review to.   

`answers has_many reviews
review belongs to user`

So I want to find all answers the user has not contributed a review to.

Comment: Can you tell me what it prints `Answer.joins(:reviews).where.not(:reviews => {:user_id => 1}).to_sql` ? Because to me this looks correct query.

Comment: ```Answer.joins(:reviews).where.not(:reviews => {:user_id => 1}).to_sql

 => "SELECT \"answers\".* FROM \"answers\" INNER JOIN \"reviews\" ON \"reviews\".\"answer_id\" = \"answers\".\"id\" WHERE (\"reviews\".\"user_id\" != 1)"```

Answer (score 0):

This is all I have so far.  It's 2 queries so not ideal.

```
Answer.where.not(id: @user.reviews.pluck(:answer_id))
```

So I'm posting here for others to have an answer if nothing better comes up.